# Handling loops in expl3

Tags: expl3, loops

I expected this inside `\clist_map`, but not in this code. The "dummy" question, probably...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\pairwise}{mmm}{
    \clist_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_clist #1
    \clist_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_clist #2
    \clist_clear:N #3
    \bool_until_do:nn {\clist_if_empty_p:N \l_tmpa_clist}{
        \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl
        \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl
        \clist_put_right:Nn #3 {\l_tmpa_tl / \l_tmpb_tl}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\this{1,2,3,4,5}
\def\that{a,b,c,d,e}

There is \{\this\} and \{\that\}.

\pairwise{\this}{\that}{\result}
\def\expected{1/a,2/b,3/c,4/d,5/e}

Why \{\result\} not equal \{\expected\}?

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `\clist_put_right:Nn` will leave `\l_tmpa_tl` in the input, i.e. at the time of calling `\result` to check for the equality, `\l_tmpa_tl` contains `5` and `\l_tmpb_tl` contains `e`.

However, to get the pairwise content `X/Y`, the current value of `\l_tmpa_tl` and `\l_tmpb_tl` must be evaluated (expanded) and stored to the `\clist` variable, so use the `x` type:

`\clist_put_right:Nx #3 {\l_tmpa_tl/\l_tmpb_tl}`

Most likely a `\seq` list could be faster, but this depends on the use case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\pairwise}{mmm}{
  \clist_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_clist #1
  \clist_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_clist #2
  \clist_clear:N #3
  \bool_until_do:nn {\clist_if_empty_p:N \l_tmpa_clist}{
    \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl
    \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl
    \clist_put_right:Nx #3 {\l_tmpa_tl / \l_tmpb_tl}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\this{1,2,3,4,5}
\def\that{a,b,c,d,e}

There is \{\this\} and \{\that\}.

\pairwise{\this}{\that}{\result}
\def\expected{1/a,2/b,3/c,4/d,5/e}

Now \{\result\} is equal to \{\expected\}?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! It will be necessary to carefully study specification of arguments.

Comment: @VasiliyKomarov: Yes, that can be quite confusing when starting with `expl3`

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the *value* of the token list variable, not the token list.

Here's a different approach using sequences and `\seq_mapthread_function:NNN`, that traverses two sequences and hands the items to a two argument function.

You can give a different output separator as optional argument to `\pairwise, so for example

```
\pairwise[|]{a,b}{1,2}{\result}
```

would define `\result` to `a/1|b/2`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\pairwise}{O{,}mmm}
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:No \l_komarov_first_seq { #2 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:No \l_komarov_second_seq { #3 }
  \seq_clear:N \l_komarov_output_seq
  \seq_mapthread_function:NNN
    \l_komarov_first_seq
    \l_komarov_second_seq
    \komarov_addentry:nn
  \tl_set:Nx #4 { \seq_use:Nn \l_komarov_output_seq { #1 } }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_komarov_first_seq
\seq_new:N \l_komarov_second_seq
\seq_new:N \l_komarov_output_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_from_clist:Nn { No }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \komarov_addentry:nn
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_komarov_output_seq { #1 / #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand\this{1,2,3,4,5}
\newcommand\that{a,b,c,d,e}

There is \{\this\} and \{\that\}.

\pairwise{\this}{\that}{\result}
\newcommand\expected{1/a,2/b,3/c,4/d,5/e}

Now \{\result\} equals \{\expected\}

\pairwise{1,2,3,4,5}{a,b,c,d,e}{\newresult}

Also \{\newresult\} equals \{\expected\}

\end{document}
```

[image]